# Can I fetch api every time that props change on ComponentDidUpdate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

As you see my code, I want to fetch API `contentUrl` every its change from props.
but browser throw error like this. Have someone help me?.

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
>   This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
>   To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the
>   componentWillUnmount method.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Issue is clearly states that : **Can't perform a React state update on
>   an unmounted component**
>
> **So check if the component is unmounted before setting up state**, `_isMounted`

Code Snippet Ref from : **[HERE](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-warning-cant-call-setstate-on-an-unmounted-component)** , Hope this will clear all your doubts

```
class News extends Component {
  _isMounted = false;  // <----- HERE

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      news: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true; // <----- HERE

    axios
      .get('YOUR_URL')
      .then(result => {
        if (this._isMounted) { // <----- CHECK HERE BEFORE SETTING UP STATE
          this.setState({
            news: result.data.hits,
          });
        }
      });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false; // <----- HERE
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, if a call is done and your component is unmounted, a setState will be called.

You can prevent this with a condition:

```js
_isMount = true;

componentDidUpdate() {
  this.props.getContentJSON(url).then(() => {
    if(this._isMount){
      this.setState({...})
    }
  })
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this._isMount = false;
}
```

or control your call :

```js
controller = new AbortController();


componentDidUpdate() {
  // I use fetch here but you can adapte to your code
  fetch(url, { signal: controller.signal }).then(() => {
      this.setState({...})
  })
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  controller.abort();
}
```